# Install numpy to use within plpython3u in postgres 9.6 for Windows 2012 (64 bit)

Tags: postgresql, windows-server-2012, plpython

I am trying to install numpy to use within plpython3u in postgres 9.6 for
Windows 2012 (64 bit) but I run into dependency problems.

1) I have installed Postgres 9.6 from EnterpriseDB and the language pack,
which automatically installs Python 3.3.  <- is there a way to install a newer version of Python?

I have done `CREATE EXTENSION plpython3u;` and it works correctly.

I tried to install python modules with:   `pip3.exe install numpy`   and
`python -m pip install --user numpy`   but numpy-1.12.1 returns an error:

> raise RuntimeError("Python version 2.7 or >= 3.4 required.")

If I try to install an older version of numpy==1.10.4, there are a number
of errors about blas and atlas and fortran compilers not being available -
so I didn't pursue that avenue much further.

2) If I install Python 3.6 separately, when CREATing EXTENSION plpython3u,
I get the

> ERROR:  could not load library "C:/Program
>   Files/PostgreSQL/9.6/lib/plpython3.dll": The specified module could
>   not be found.

The DLL **is** in that location, but the utility "depends" shows that it is
compiled for python33 and not python36, and those dependencies are
missing.  Could I replace the plpython3.dll file somehow to get it to work
with Python 3.6?

Surely someone has installed numpy for plpython3u in postgres for Windows,
but I could not find any solutions so far..

Thanks

Peter

Comment: In a cmd shell, what does `python -version` (or `--version`) return?

Comment: For option 1): `Python 3.3.4`  
Option 2) is no longer installed, but it used to show that Python 3.6 was installed correctly.